# How do i get item by ID from a loop of Rows.count

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint

What I am trying to do is that I want to update the status of any checked item from gridview.

[image]

My Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Input string was not in a correct format.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList drpDwnStat = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("drpDwnStatus");
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("List");
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        if (chkBox.Checked == true)
                            {
                                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkBox.NamingContainer;
                                int index = row.RowIndex;

                                SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text));
                                {
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    newStat["Status"] = drpDwnStat.SelectedItem.Text;

                                    newStat.Update();
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format." which line does this occur?

Comment: As Grant Winney said: You probably parse the wrong cell's input. I think you should try index `0`: `int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text`

Comment: @Ian it occurs in this line SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text));

Comment: @khlr yes I have already tried index '0' that but still same error

Comment: @Ian Yes I understand, I first tried with index `Cells[0]` but still error

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari what does the error say? And how the `GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text` string looks like?

Comment: @Grant Winney @Ian @khlr Or is there any other way to get item ID? instead of writing `GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text));`

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari it is OK to do that, except that you got to be sure of the two indexers you use there `index` value and the `Cells[0].Text`... Checking them and make sure that they are correct is a lot better approach. Likely you simply do not point to the right cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text))
```

You seem to get the `int` value from `Cells[1]`. But according to your picture, the `int` text `ID` is in `Cells[0]` (which is the **first** column in the row).

`Cells[1]` refer to the **second** column:

```
Diryas
Soban
Attiq
test
```

`Cells[0]` refer to the **first** column:

```
3
4
5
8
```

Comment: Yes, I changed my line `SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text));` to 
`SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text))` but still I get this error [link](http://i.imgur.com/PanD5dF.png?1)

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari I understand... what I am saying is, try to debug it. *not* to mention what is the error, because the error is definitely caused by wrong item in the `GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text`. What we need to know is the value of `index` and of `Cells[0].Text`, *not* the fact that it produces error. We want to know the values of them so that we can know *why* we get the error. This is solely aimed to solve your issue faster.

Comment: Went through debug, index value is 0 [index](http://imgur.com/BWvxGPC) and this is the cell value [Cell Value](http://i.imgur.com/x7STKme.png?1) plz check links

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari close enough, but please expand the `Cells` value, check for `Cells[0].Text`. In fact, you could even create a temporary string: `string justtocheck = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text` and then see what is the value for `justtocheck`

Comment: Value = null [justocheck](http://i.imgur.com/NGQtCVs.png?1) Value = "" [justtocheck](http://i.imgur.com/KoduUKa.png?1) I dont get it

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari the `null` is because you haven't run the line. It is OK. But the `Value = ""` is *not* OK... Now we know what is the cause of the error, at least. As far as I know, there is a way to get the `Cells` value from `GridView` by using the column `string` `Id`. But just to be sure. You may check what is the value for `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text`, `GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text`, `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text`, `GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text` Just to be sure that you can get any text in the first place...

Comment: Also, note that you can actually get the value of `Cells` with `string` `index` like this: `GridView1.Rows[1].Cells["ID"].Text`, just in case you do not know..

Comment: Great, found first ID on `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text` [firstID](http://i.imgur.com/896OpOX.png?1)

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari what you need is the `ID` number though... :s I suspect that will be in your `Rows[0].Cells[0]` also, I suspect your `index` do **not** give real value `0`. What you see as `0` in your `index` is probably before you execute the line. After you execute the line, you probably do not get `0`. But please check first what is in the `Rows[0].Cells[0]`. What you need is to know where your `3, 4, 5, 8` numbers are located.

Comment: I tried `GridView1.Rows[1].Cells["ID"].Text` but error [link](http://i.imgur.com/Ur3f7ng.png?1)

Comment: @MohammedMoosaLaghari OK, don't use that `string` and I just realize that you are writing `Web` app, not `Desktop`

Comment: Okay.. so can I use my loop integer `i` instead of `index` `i gives me value 0 to rows.count` like this `GridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Text`

Comment: hmm I will try to locate my `3, 4, 5, 8`

Answer (score 1):

Okay with the help of Mr.Ian, I found my error and here is the correct code to get item ID.

```
//NOTE: Rows[i] this i is from the loop (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
int justtocheck = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);

SPListItem newStat = list.Items.GetItemById(justtocheck);
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        newStat["Status"] = drpDwnStat.SelectedItem.Text;

                        newStat.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
```